# Disabling Buttons after launching an application in Android

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I currently developing a Content Management app in Kiosk Mode. I pattern this in [**Surelock Kiosk Lockdown**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock). There's an admin password in order to allow application to run inside the app. The buttons like Home, Back and Recent Task App are disabled in this app. However when I launch a certain app, Back button and Recent Task App are enabled again.

What I'd like to happen is that when the user launch an app, the Recent Task app button and Back button are disabled just like in Content Management App. I am stuck in searching and finding ways on how to do this. Please help me on how to do this. Thank you.

BTW, I'm using this code to disable Buttons:

```
// Disable Recent Task App
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed!");

    if (!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus!");

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        closeDialog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}

// Disable Volume Buttons and Back Button
private final List hijackKeys = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP,
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (hijackKeys.contains(event.getKeyCode())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer to this?